# "Unknown Device" efibootmgr -v output (18.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, boot-repair

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS from flash drive, and when i execute `efibootmgr -v` display me this:

[image]

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,d07149ff-6aee-469e-849a-6645f1f7a068,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0002* ubuntuinstallusb  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(0,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x5092863d,0x3cde8c,0x1340)/File(\efi\boot\grubx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0003* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,59d7a7fa-f8df-40d4-b078-396f9561face,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0006* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,6cdbbc50-0a2f-44b5-a361-224073cad8c4,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Someone can me explain my `efibootmgr -v` output like why is a **Unknow Device** or what mean **RC** and the end of Boots. How can solve it?

I ll explain how i installed ubuntu to be more rigorous.

All start when i plug my flash drive in my laptop. i selected the usb to be the first to boot and the screen show me this.

[image]

To solve it i went to security and i selected ***Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing***

[image]

Then **USB0** next **efi** next **boot** next **grubx64.efi** and i called ***ubuntuinstallusb*** and then i reboot pc and i went to BIOS again and selected ***EFI File Boot 0: ubuntuinstallusb*** first to boot

[image]

Then worked and i continuous like a typical instalation, On instalation type i selected ***Something else*** and my configuration was that:

[image]

(Note: /dev/sdb is the flash drive)

And i finished the instalation. When I reboot the pc the screen displayed me this:

[image]

I selected **ok** then i saw this:

[image]

I choose the first (Unknown Device: MQ...) one and the screen showed me this:

[image]

(Note: This option **only showed up the first time** when i started ubuntu)

Then i press any key and saw this:

[image]

I choosed the **Continue Boot** and Ubuntu start normally then in terminal i writted `efibootmgr -v` and show me the 'error' which is described in the beginning. Thx

Comment: Standard Acer. I thought you could boot installer without trust and only after install did you need it. You have to set trust from within UEFI to change name from unknown to whatever name you like. Unique to all Acer. Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the BIOS. I had the same problem two years ago and that solved my problem